# Is this sentence is a conditional? "Marta on if she would ever make a tinder account"

Tags: grammar, conditionals, would

Is it correct to use this struct? (If + noun + would)

I was looking for any examples of this structure, and every time I received an answer that this is a conditional.

I have also asked chatgpt, and it answered that is a conditional sentence as well, but how can it be conditional if there is only one part of it?

Comment: It sounds like a newspaper article where someone comments on this topic (I.e., whether she would ever make an account). Is the context something like this? If so "on if" isn't really working as a unit.

Comment: I wouldn't be inclined to call that string of words a sentence, conditional or otherwise.

Comment: *if* should be *whether*.

Comment: Source? Please tell us where you found this line, and provide a link to it. Context? What was said before or after? Author? Native speaker? Casual speech? There is not enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

> "Marta on if she would ever make a tinder account"

This is not a sentence and it is a title.

It is not conditional. It is a fragment. It is of a style used in headlines and titles. Nouns, of any sort, cannot be conditional.

On = on the subject of

*if she would ever make a tinder account* is a noun clause and the object of the preposition "on".

Compare

"Quirk on English Grammar"

or

"Ayres on Philosophy".

"Greybeard on why Einstein was wrong."

Etc.

Comment: Indeed. What's important is that this is the interrogative use of *if,* not the conditional one; you could replace it here with "whether."